Google管理コンソール等で作成したアプリからメールが取得されていることを確認する方法について
.NetFrameworkで作成したアプリにてGoogle.Apisのパッケージを利用しOAuth2の認証を行い、
MailKit.Net.Pop3.PopClientを用いてメールの取得を行っております。
Google管理コンソールからOAuthの認証履歴は確認できたのですが、
APIとサービスの一覧ではGmailAPIの行のリクエスト等が空欄となっており
管理画面からアクセスの確認ができませんでした。
Google管理コンソール等で作成アプリからメールが取得されていることを
確認する方法はございますでしょうか。
